# Joomla : how to fix "Undefined property: AriDocsViewerContentPlugin::$stripUSC"?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla-extensions

I try to install the ARI Docs Viewer plugin of Joomla in localhost and I always have the following error: " **Undefined property: AriDocsViewerContentPlugin::$stripUSC** "
However, all the files to be displayed are all present in the local server.
When I disable the plugin, there is no error on the site and the document does not display.
I’ve already commented the next code tip and the error goes away but the document still does not appear.

> if ($this->stripUSC) {    // Alternatively:
>   preg_replace('/[\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', "\xE2\xAF\x91", $source) but
>   it'd be slower.   $source = $this->stripUSC($source); }

Does someone here already had this error ?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: In the quote-block formatted snippet in your question, you are writing `stripUSC` as if it was both 1. A property of an object and 2. A class method.  It needs to be one or the other.  I am not acquainted with the plugin you are working with, but if `stripUSC` is a class method that expects `$source` as an argument, then you must always include the `($source)` syntax.  Perhaps you mean to write the condition as `if ($this->stripUSC($source)) {`.  If in doubt, `var_dump($this);` to see what is on offer in the class.  I can post an answer if you give a bit more clarity.

Comment: Also  if you are using Joomla, I recommend that you join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and post your support questions there.